# Clickonce .net upgrade

Tags: .net, clickonce, .net-4.5

Microsoft.Net 4.5 is coming and I want to upgrade my clickonce app when MS releases the final version.

My question is: Does the users who already have an clickonce application installed(with .net 4.0) will need to make a manual .net framework upgrade or it's going to be automaticly?

Tks

Comment: Your click once update _should_ install .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has only .NET 4 installed, they would need to install .NET 4.5 prior to installation.

Your ClickOnce application should have .NET as a prerequisite and prior to installing app, you can install .NET.

[How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How to: Specify a Support URL for Individual Prerequisites in a ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404264%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If the user has .NET 4 installed and your application targets .NET 4.5, they have to install .NET 4.5.

.NET 4 will not automatically be updated to .NET 4.5. At some point, Microsoft will start pushing out .NET 4.5 in Windows Updates, but it's way too early to anticipate the timing on that.

Comment: Even if I add as prerequisite?

Comment: setup.exe is a bootstrapper that checks for and installs the prerequisites and then kicks off the installation of the ClickOnce application itself. ClickOnce only looks for updates to itself, not to the prerequisites. You can change the prerequisite and then send a link out to the setup.exe and ask people to run it again. It will install the new prerequisites and then run the app. We couldn't rely on all of our customers doing this.

Comment: (#2) To handle changing prerequisites in our ClickOnce apps, we deploy the new version to a new URL, then deploy an update to the old version with code that will have it uninstall itself and install the new version. Pretty seamless. Uninstall/reinstall code is in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx