# Programmatically install setup.exe from ClickOnce deploy location when client is updating

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, clickonce, bootstrapper

I need to allow my client's to run the setup.exe when they would like to upgrade after this next role. We have updated the code from .NET Framework 2.0 to 4.0. I understand that the client could simply go our website and download the application from the in order to upgrade the existing as well as get the setup.exe which will check for pre-requisistes. But, I have been asked to make it so that when they choose to update from the client itself, it runs the bootstrapper first. I understand that ClickOnce does not directly support this. I am already handling the update checking/instaling programmatically by using the System.Deployement.Application namespace. Is it possible that I can just include the setup.exe in the application itself, and then run that file when user chooses to download? Maybe I can just pull the setup.exe directly from the install location when the user wants to upgrade? Has anyone accomplished this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is roughly the same problem as this question here: [Clickonce .net upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053737/clickonce-net-upgrade). If you look at the sample program it shows how to uninstall the current version and use a new URL to run setup.exe and install the new version and check for prerequisites.  It could be modified or used directly to meet your needs.

Comment: I ended up just using Process.Start("<URL for setup.exe>") in order to handle the updating/checking new requirements. Along with some messageboxes it worked quite beautifully. Thanks